# Absolute div not not staying in parent relative div when resizing

Tags: html, css

Context: I have a  relative div which contain an image and a card with some information. The card is overlapping the bottom of the image with an absolute position but when resizing, the card does not stay at the same position within his parent div and goes following the rule of another container:

[image]

Achievement: What I am trying to do is whine resizing the browser, I want the card to stay at the same position on the image (overlapping).

Here is my html:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  background-color: #181719;
}

main {
  padding: 46px 76px 46px 77px;
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 1px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Crimson Pro";
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  flex: 0.4;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 177px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 139px;
}

.main_image {

  border: #828282 solid;
  position: relative;
}

.main_image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Lora";
  font-size: 48px;
}

.text_presentation i {
  margin-left: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text_presentation p {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 410px;
}

.text_presentation a {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 48px;
  position: absolute;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 410px;
  height: 189px;
  background-color: #181719;
  top: 477px;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 32px;
  left: 300px;
  border: solid red;
}

.card_info {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.card img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 18px 0px 0px 31px;
}

.card h3,
h4 {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 500;
}

.card h3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  top: 23px;
  left: 100px;
}

.card h4 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #828282;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 202px;
  top: 48px;
  left: 100px;
}

.card p {
  font-family: "Lora";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 287px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 28px;
}

footer {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 206px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Interior Design</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Pro:wght@200;400&family=Lora&family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/2.0/LineIcons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">
          <p>This Interior</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Collection</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text_presentation">
          <h1>Modern Interior</h1>
          <p>
            A full-Service residential & commercial interior design and staging
            company offering professional organizing & eco-services.
          </p>
          <a>Read more<i class="lni lni-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="main_image">
          <img src="/photo1.png" alt="photo" />
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card_info">
              <img src="/photo2.png" alt="photo2" />
              <h3>Aliza Webbler</h3>
              <h4>Interior Designer</h4>
            </div>
            <p>Designed in 2020 by Aliza Webber</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p>Rémy @ Devchallenge.io</p>
      </footer>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

I guess I am missing something but I do not know where.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not an immediate answer to your positioning question, but an observation that you have quite a few fixed dimensions in the CSS - this will make it difficult to read on a small device - will have to swipe to see all the page left/right for example.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, on smartphone will do all the media queries that everything fit on a page as a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes I made are in classes: `.card` , `.main_image` and `.main_image img`

The way I made the changes makes this part of the web page responsive.

On the `.card` element the absolute position is replaced by a relative one. This allows you to position the element more flexibly.

For `.main_image` and `.main_image img`. I moved the border from the DIV element to the picture. In this way, the DIV element remains as a package for both elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Interior Design</title>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Pro:wght@200;400&family=Lora&family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/2.0/LineIcons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
</head>

<body>






    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            color: white;
            background-color: #181719;
        }

        main {
            padding: 46px 76px 46px 77px;
            max-width: 1440px;
            margin: auto;
            border: solid 1px;
        }

        nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .logo {
            font-family: "Crimson Pro";
            border: solid 1px;
            padding: 8px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 200;
        }

        ul {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            list-style: none;
            flex: 0.4;
            font-family: "Montserrat";
            font-weight: 500;
            font-style: normal;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            margin-top: 177px;
            justify-content: space-between;
            gap: 139px;
        }

        .main_image {
            position: relative;
        }

        .main_image img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            border: #828282 solid;
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: "Lora";
            font-size: 48px;
        }

        .text_presentation i {
            margin-left: 15px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .text_presentation p {
            font-family: "Montserrat";
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-top: 40px;
            width: 410px;
        }

        .text_presentation a {
            font-family: "Montserrat";
            font-weight: 600;
            margin-top: 48px;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .card {
            position: relative;
            width: 410px;
            height: 189px;
            background-color: #181719;
            border: solid red;
            margin-top: -80px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: 3%;
        }

        .card_info {
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
        }

        .card img {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            margin: 18px 0px 0px 31px;
        }

        .card h3,
        h4 {
            font-family: "Montserrat";
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        .card h3 {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 14px;
            top: 23px;
            left: 100px;
        }

        .card h4 {
            position: absolute;
            color: #828282;
            font-size: 12px;
            width: 202px;
            top: 48px;
            left: 100px;
        }

        .card p {
            font-family: "Lora";
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 24px;
            width: 287px;
            margin: 30px 0px 0px 28px;
        }

        footer {
            font-family: "Montserrat";
            font-size: 17px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 206px;
        }
    </style>











    <main>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <p>This Interior</p>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Collection</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text_presentation">
                <h1>Modern Interior</h1>
                <p>
                    A full-Service residential & commercial interior design and staging
                    company offering professional organizing & eco-services.
                </p>
                <a>Read more<i class="lni lni-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="main_image">
                <img src="https://blog.54ka.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/profile-view-of-a-brown-horse_by_54ka.jpg"
                    alt="photo" />
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card_info">
                        <img src="/photo2.png" alt="photo2" />
                        <h3>Aliza Webbler</h3>
                        <h4>Interior Designer</h4>
                    </div>
                    <p>Designed in 2020 by Aliza Webber</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>Rémy @ Devchallenge.io</p>
        </footer>
    </main>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes you got it right ! how did you manage to get this ?

Comment: I wrote a description of the classes in the post. You can give a positive vote and mark this post as an Accepted Answer